# how to change stylesheet dynamically in angular?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change my bootstrap.css file to change the theme of my app:

```
$scope.changeStyle = function (style) {
    $scope.myStyle = style + '/bootstrap.min.css';
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Mystyle is defined in the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{myStyle}}">
```

The question is how to get it working? here is a plunkr reference:http://plnkr.co/edit/t0fZLB?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS switch stylesheets based on user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514330/angularjs-switch-stylesheets-based-on-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your change event is not fired. You can do like this,

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownCountry">
            <li ng-repeat="country in data.locations.countries | orderBy:'country'" ng-model="country.Capital">
                <a ng-click="changeStyle(country.Capital)">{{country.country}}</a>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ViGr29?p=preview)